# Share icon (vector) shows in design but not in app

Tags: java, android, vector

I have used vector for creating a share icon across card view.

Implementing in HolderClass

```
class CommasHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
SimpleDraweeView commasImage;
ImageButton shareButton;

public CommasHolder(View cardView){
    super(cardView);
    commasImage = (SimpleDraweeView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_image);
    shareButton = (ImageButton) cardView.findViewById(R.id.share_button);
}
}
```

Layout

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share_button"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"/>
```

Vector

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M18,16.08c-0.76,0 -1.44,0.3 -1.96,0.77L8.91,12.7c0.05,-0.23 0.09,-0.46 0.09,-0.7s-0.04,-0.47 -0.09,-0.7l7.05,-4.11c0.54,0.5 1.25,0.81 2.04,0.81 1.66,0 3,-1.34 3,-3s-1.34,-3 -3,-3 -3,1.34 -3,3c0,0.24 0.04,0.47 0.09,0.7L8.04,9.81C7.5,9.31 6.79,9 6,9c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3c0.79,0 1.5,-0.31 2.04,-0.81l7.12,4.16c-0.05,0.21 -0.08,0.43 -0.08,0.65 0,1.61 1.31,2.92 2.92,2.92 1.61,0 2.92,-1.31 2.92,-2.92s-1.31,-2.92 -2.92,-2.92z"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have You Added This To your Gradle file

```
 android {  defaultConfig {  
 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
}   }
```

Comment: Yes I added it in gradle file